# Matplotlib hexbin gridsize keeps changing

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm trying to use matplotlib's hexbin plotting function to programmatically plot the regression errors of several neural networks that I'm training.

I've set the gridsize parameter to a specific value, 100, for both the x and y directions. However, in the plots that are getting saved, the gridsize seems to keep changing, which has been very frustrating. Below are two different figures, produced using the same function, with no changes, 3 minutes apart. The data that were used to create the functions are exactly the same size and shape. I'm a bit lost as to what I'm doing wrong at this point.

Figure 1, this is roughly how I want the hexgrid to look:
[image: this is roughly how I want the hexgrid to look]

Figure 2, hex sizes are much too small in this one
[image: hex sizes are much too small in this one]

```
def plot_errors_hex(x, y, net_dir):
    """Uses pyplot's hexbin to plot errors using a jet colormap."""
    plt.figure(1)
    plt.hexbin(x + 512/2, y + 512/2, gridsize=(100,100))
    plt.plot(256, 256, 'ro')

    plt.ylim(0, 512)
    plt.xlim(0, 512)
    plt.colorbar()

    f1 = plt.gcf()
    f1.set_size_inches(5, 4)
    plt.savefig(os.path.join(net_dir, 'error_plot_hex.png'))
    plt.clf()
```

Comment: Did you try using a smaller gridsize such as `gridsize=(70,70))` or `(80, 80)`?

Comment: Does it help to set the axis limits via the `extent` keyword of `plt.hexbin` instead of using `plt.xlim` and `plt.ylim`? As in
`plt.hexbin(x, y, gridsize = (100,100), extent=[0, 512, 0, 512])`

Comment: Neither of these changes work.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, something seems wrong with the 2nd gridsize parameter (i.e. the y-gridsize).